# Connection health check for sftp with JSch

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I need to check the health of the SFTP connection using JSch liberary. I have used the following approach. Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
public boolean checkConnection() throws JSchException {
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = sch.getSession(username, host);
        session.setPort(PORT);   
        session.setPassword(password);
        session.connect();
        return true;
    } catch(Exception ex){
        LOG.error("Error while connecting to SFTP", ex);
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Thank you Martin. Should we also check for the channel connection?

Comment: Sorry, but we cannot decide for you. We do not know what is a purpose of your test.

Comment: sch cannot be resolved. please check that